# Decide the clickable status of check box according to json response

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a check box in my application and it should be clickable when `mayoBase` returns `true` and its shouldn't be clickable when `mayoBase` returns `false`. I have tried the below mentioned code, but it crashes. I have attached my logcat, how can I overcome this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            List<String> crust = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> descriptionHalf = new ArrayList<String>();
            final List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> extraDescription = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")) {
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptionHalf.add(object.getString("Description"));

                    Log.i("IsMayoBaseAvailable",
                            object.getString("IsMayoBaseAvailable"));

                    String isMayoBaseAvailable = object
                            .getString("IsMayoBaseAvailable");

                    mayoBaseCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_mayobase);
                    if (isMayoBaseAvailable.contains("true")) {
                        mayoBaseCB.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        mayoBaseCB.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    JSONArray subMenuArray = object
                            .getJSONArray("SubMenuEntity");

                    for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
                        JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray
                                .getJSONObject(j);
                        Log.i("Crust", subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));
                        crust.add(subMenuObject.getString("Crust"));

                        Log.i("Description",
                                subMenuObject.getString("Description"));
                        description.add(subMenuObject.getString("Description"));

                        JSONArray extraItemEntityArray = subMenuObject
                                .getJSONArray("ExtraItemEntity");

                        for (int k = 0; k < extraItemEntityArray.length(); k++) {
                            JSONObject objectE = extraItemEntityArray
                                    .getJSONObject(k);

                            if ((objectE.getString("Description")) != null
                                    && (objectE.getString("Type")).equals("E")) {

                                extraDescription.add(objectE
                                        .getString("Description"));
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    // mayoBaseCB.setEnabled(false);
                }
```

Comment: Your array is empty??

Comment: Not empty. mayoBase has values

Answer (score 0):

If this condition `(object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")` is false, you're not adding to `mayoBase`, so `mayoBase` can be shorter than `responseJson.length()`, yet you're calling `String strIsVag = mayoBase.get(i);` on every iteration of the loop.

This can't work, unless above condition is always `true`.

Something like this might work for you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

    if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")) {
        Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
        descriptionHalf.add(object.getString("Description"));

        Log.i("IsMayoBaseAvailable", object.getString("IsMayoBaseAvailable"));

        String isMayoBaseAvailable = object.getString("IsMayoBaseAvailable");

        mayoBaseCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_mayobase);
        if (isMayoBaseAvailable.contains("true")) {
            mayoBaseCB.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mayoBaseCB.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    mayoBaseCB.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Ok I got what u are saying. Can u suggest me any other way to achieve this task

Comment: Sorry, must have been dreaming. Try the updated example, you don't need that array at all.

Comment: I have uploaded my complete code, can u check it.. when i debug it goes to if and else statement correctly. But when I run the application and check then all the items shows as setEnabled false.

Comment: The code behaves correctly when you debug it, but not when you run it? Congratulations, that's called a Heisenbug [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug] difficult to figure out, and impossible remotely, so you're on your own. One thing I noticed is you're talking about "all the items", but there is only one `CheckBox` in your code...

Comment: I'm working with a grid, so it has many items. This check box is inside a item.. Lol i'll try to find it out..

Comment: I cant figure that out, so i posted another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832939/if-else-doesnt-work-properly-with-my-check-box. If u could figure please help me