# If-else doesn't work properly with my check box

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a grid in my application and when I select an item it load the items prospectively. I want to allow to select the check box only when `isMayoBaseAvailable` returns true.

This is the code I used, when I used this code and debug it work correctly, but when I run the application and check it always go inside the false (In all the items). Why does it happens?

I have shown my logcat as well.

```
@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            List<String> crust = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> descriptionHalf = new ArrayList<String>();
            final List<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> extraDescription = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                    String isMayoBaseAvailable = object
                            .getString("IsMayoBaseAvailable");

                    mayoBaseCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_mayobase);
                    if (isMayoBaseAvailable.contains("true")) {
                        mayoBaseCB.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        mayoBaseCB.setEnabled(false);
                    }
```

Logcat shows some items has `isMayoBaseAvailable` as true and some has as false.

[image]

Comment: please, add the json data.

Comment: try using switch instead of if-else

Comment: just give the data that you are running against it, and also the logcat of the time it wasn't run with an attached debugger, also show more code is this an AsyncTask? if so please show where its called from

Comment: replace your .contains with .equals("true");

Comment: I have updated my json response. that is for  1item. same as that I have many items like 50 in the json response. 1st item has  "IsMayoBaseAvailable":false, then I have true items in some places